# Tests order execution using jmeter maven plugin

Tags: automation, jmeter, performance-testing, maven-plugin

I'm traying to execute few Jmeter tests using Jmeter maven plugin in my case the tests order can be important, I tried to figure how can I control the different tests order using the Jmeter maven plugin with no success , any idea if it's possible ?

```
<!-- The flows we want to execute -->
    <testFilesIncluded>
       <jMeterTestFile>flows/flow1</jMeterTestFile>
       <jMeterTestFile>flows/flow2</jMeterTestFile>
       <jMeterTestFile>flows/flow3</jMeterTestFile>
    </testFilesIncluded>
```

in this case 3 runs first then 1 and last is 2

Answer (score 0):

The order of execution is not guaranteed, if you need to run tests in particular order either execute your Maven build 3 times providing a single .jmx script or combine these scripts into one "umbrella" script which will be invoking the others stored as [Test Fragments](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-manage-large-jmeter-scripts-jmeter-test-fragments) via [Include Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller) or [Module Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller).